# How do I sort a 2D numpy array in this specific way

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I realize there are quite a number of 'how to sort numpy array'-questions on here already. But I could not find how to do it in this specific way.

I have an array similar to this:

```
array([[1,0,1,],
    [0,0,1],
    [1,1,1],
    [1,1,0]])
```

I want to sort the rows, keeping the order within the rows the same. So I expect the following output:

```
array([[0,0,1,],
    [1,0,1],
    [1,1,0],
    [1,1,1]])
```

Comment: `a[np.lexsort(a.T[::-1])]`

Comment: Correct! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dot` and `argsort`:

```
a[a.dot(2**np.arange(a.shape[1])[::-1]).argsort()]
# array([[0, 0, 1],
#        [1, 0, 1],
#        [1, 1, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1]])
```

The idea is to convert the rows into integers.

```
a.dot(2**np.arange(a.shape[1])[::-1])
# array([5, 1, 7, 6])
```

Then, find the sorted indices and use that to reorder `a`:

```
a.dot(2**np.arange(a.shape[1])[::-1]).argsort()
# array([1, 0, 3, 2])
```

---

My tests show this is slightly faster than `lexsort`.

```
a = a.repeat(1000, axis=0)

%timeit a[np.lexsort(a.T[::-1])]
%timeit a[a.dot(2**np.arange(a.shape[1])[::-1]).argsort()]

230 µs ± 18.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
192 µs ± 4.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Verify correctness:

```
np.array_equal(a[a.dot(2**np.arange(a.shape[1])[::-1]).argsort()], 
               a[np.lexsort(a.T[::-1])])
# True
```

Comment: `np.packbits` is probably a bit faster than doing it manually.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thanks, I initially considered `a[np.packbits(a, axis=1).ravel().argsort()]` however `packbits` does not return the same result as the `dot` version so I cannot confirm how correct it is. Any idea why the results differ? Is it the dtype?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Okay, reading the documentation, I see `packbits` pads zeros at the end, not the start (weird). So this means that the relative ordering should remain the same. Let me update.

Comment: It doesn't? Does your `a` have more than 8 columns? Then things become a bit hairy, because `packbits` generates bytes, so you can't just `ravel` etc.

Comment: @PaulPanzer No, I'm using the same data as given. `np.packbits(a)` does not give me the correct output unless I add `axis=1`.

Comment: Ok, I think to make it general (meaning up to 64 columns) you'll probably need something like `raw = np.packbits(a, axis=1)`; `out = np.zeros((A.shape[0], 1), 'u8')`; `N = raw.shape[1]`; `idx = np.s_[:, 7:7-N if N<8 else None:-1] if sys.byteorder=='little' else np.s_[:, :N]`; `out.view('u1')[idx] = raw` and then use `out` with `argsort`. Not sure this will still be faster than yours. Feel free to use this. I won't post it myself. No point in needlessly annoying a prospective mod, is there ;-)) Speaking of which, how is the campaign going?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Let me spend a good amount of time digesting that before I decide to use it :) Also, I consider your comments far from annoying, quite the polar opposite in fact—please continue to enlighten us with your wealth of NumPy knowledge, lord knows we need more of it in this tag. Re:elections, there's a lot of strong candidates this time. I don't think I'll win but I didn't expect to win from the beginning anyway. The support has been overwhelming and I'm happy to have come this far. The reason I decided to run this time is because I decided to become the change I wanted to see. :D